# How to connect to Alexa with my app controlling my home device?

Tags: iot, alexa-skills-kit, smart-device

I have a stove which is controlled by an app. I can turn on and off using the app. How to integrate Alexa on the app so that I can control the stove with Alexa?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to **buy it for direct use case** and not build yourself you can found nice smart plug that connect to your stove. Your stove is always on but the plug will switch off or on via Alexa.

Here is one ready to use smart plug : https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GJL9P9S22S2HBUDF

If you want **to build it yourself** (more fun), you can buy some smart plug controlled by RF 433MHZ or Bluetooth, etc.

Then you connect an arduino and the smart plug with a small transmitter.

Last step is too connect the arduino over internet (MQTT broker for example) and you pass data (on/off) from Alexa -> Broker -> Arduino -> SmartPlug / Stove

I did the same for a ordinary lamp : https://medium.com/@arradimohamed/voice-controlled-smart-home-with-amazon-alexa-skill-and-ios-app-3a8622bf2b55